# how get company wise highest salaried employee name from this schema

Tags: sql, oracle

the database schema is like this:

employee(emp_id#,person_name,dob,street,city)

company(company_id#, company_name,city)

works(emp_id,company_id,salary)

manages(emp_id,manager_id)

```
insert into employee values('e-1','dipankar pal','15-jul-1997','h.m raod','kolkata');
insert into employee values('e-2','subhadip roy','15-jan-1997','garia','kolkata');
```

the manages table may be little bit confusing, here are some data I've inserted to clear my point

```
insert into manages values('e-3','e-1');
insert into manages values('e-4','e-1');
insert into manages values('e-5','e-1');
insert into manages values('e-6','e-2');
insert into manages values('e-7','e-2');
```

Comment: Which database software is this? You've tagged mysql, oracle, and postgresql.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: oh thanks actually i'm new to stackoverflow :) by the way i'm using oracle 10g express edition

Comment: Then add the `oracle` tag

Comment: What have you tried so far?????

Comment: select e.emp_id, c.company_name from employee e, company c, works w where c.company_id=w.company_id and e.emp_id=w.emp_id
and salary=(select max(salary) from works);     but it showing only the highest salary from the entire table not company wise !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT Z.COMPANY_NAME, E.PERSON_NAME, Z.HIGHEST_SALARY
FROM
    (SELECT C.COMPANY_ID, C.COMPANY_NAME, MAX(W.SALARY) AS HIGHEST_SALARY
    FROM
    WORKS W INNER JOIN COMPANY C
    ON W.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID
    GROUP BY C.COMPANY_ID, C.COMPANY_NAME ) Z
INNER JOIN WORKS W
ON Z.COMPANY_ID = W.COMPANY_ID
AND Z.HIGHEST_SALARY = W.SALARY
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E
ON W.EMP_ID = E.EMP_ID
ORDER BY Z.HIGHEST_SALARY DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select company.company_name,employee.person_name as employee_name,y.salary as salary from employee,company,
(select works.emp_id,works.company_id,works.salary from works,
(select company_id,max(salary) as high from works group by(company_id)
)x where high=works.salary) y
where employee.emp_id=y.emp_id and company.company_id=y.company_id order by company_name
;
```